# Meteor.js - How to observeChanges() from client side

Tags: meteor

I'm a total newbie to Meteor. I'm trying to create a proof of concept using Meteor where updates to the Mongo oplog get displayed to the browser screen.

For now, I'm trying to adapt the simple-todos to this purpose. I got the server logging updates to the terminal but no idea how to transfer this to the client browser screen?

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {
    // counter starts at 0
    Session.setDefault('counter', 0);

    Template.hello.helpers({
        counter: function () {
            return Session.get('counter');
        }
    });

    Template.hello.events({
        'click button': function () {
            // increment the counter when button is clicked
            Session.set('counter', Session.get('counter') + 1);
        }
    });
}

if(Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        // code to run on server at startup
        var Test = new Mongo.Collection('test');
        var query = Test.find({});
        var init = true;
        query.observeChanges({
            added: function(id, fields) {
                if(!init)
                    console.log('doc inserted');
            },
            changed: function(id, fields) {
                console.log('doc updated');
            },
            removed: function() {
                console.log('doc removed');
            }
        });
        init = false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define collection for both - server and client:

```
//collection Test for client and server
var Test = new Mongo.Collection('test');
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  //subscribe for collection test
  Meteor.subscribe('test');
  Template.hello.helpers({
    test: function() {
      var query = Test.find();
      query.observeChanges({
        added: function(id, fields) {
          console.log('doc inserted');
        },
        changed: function(id, fields) {
          console.log('doc updated');
        },
        removed: function() {
          console.log('doc removed');
        }
      });
      return query;
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('test', function() {
    return Test.find();
  });
}
```

For more complex app you should structure your app into multiple directories and files. Read about it in [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp).

Comment: But I heard that was unsecure.

Comment: I guess the secure way is by publish and subscribe although I'm not really sure how that would work here.

Comment: Sure you should use publish/subscribe. In your client-side collection are only data that you publish on your server. Read this and try it: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-meteor-publications-and-subscriptions/

Comment: Can you modify your answer to account for publish/subscribe?

Comment: If you want to publish all your data with Test.find({}) there is no need for publish/subscribe.

Comment: It was just the code I've come up with up to this point none of the code I wrote is required. Whatever gets the job done the right way.